# Entity Framework - How to return a strongly typed object containing multiple Entities?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6

I have three tables in SQL Server: Company, Financial and FinancialHistory.

Relationships are: 
Company -> Financial (1-1) 
Financial -> FinancialHistory (1-Many)

Having generated an Entity Model, I want to return one larger "Entity" that contains ALL the columns from Company and Financial and a select few from FinancialHistory so that I can maintain a sort across multiple GridViews at the front end. Basically I want to avoid returning a dynamic List type which is where i'm at currently, I want a more strongly typed return type.

Is there any feature in Entity Framework 6 that allows me to do this via the Model diagram or do I have to create my own class and use it separately to the Model? An example of the class and instructions would help.

NOTE: I flatten out the FinancialHistory data and create dynamic columns in a DataTable before assigning to GridViews.

Originally this was a Stored Procedure that used PIVOT and generated dynamic columns but I wanted to move it over to EF and use LINQ.

Comment: Seeing your last sentence (pivot), the answer to everything is: no. But we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to give more pointed help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying you can project the results into any type. While that type won't be updatable (you need to directly modify entity types) it works very well when querying.

```
var res = await (from cpy in myDbContent.Companies
                // get two newest financial results
                let fin = cpy.financials
                let finResRecent = fin.History.OrderByDescending(h => h.FinancialYear)
                let finResLast = finResRecent.FirstOrDefault()
                let finResPrev = finResRecent.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()
                select new {
                  Company = cpy,
                  Financials = fin,
                  LastResults = finResLast,
                  PreviousResults = finresPrev
                }
               ).ToListAsync();
```

(Inside the query many operators – like `Single` – can't be used, but `FirstOrDefault` can)